# The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match (previously not answered)

Tags: tensorflow, kotlin

I am trying to create a app that uses tensorflow model. My app crashes when `inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)` gets executed. ( got to know by commenting the lines)

```
var img=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,229,229,true)
val model = SkinDiseasesDetectionFitSizeFinal24120210504.newInstance(this)
val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 229, 229, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
var tensorimage=TensorImage.fromBitmap(img)
var byteBuffer=tensorimage.buffer
inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)
```

This is the error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.azsky.skincancerdetection, PID: 31954
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match.
```

Can someone help me out in this?

Answer (score 0):

in the process of converting tensorflow to TfLite if you use optimization then you should read from here first
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization. it is said that the optimize version is 4 times smaller so you need to create your byte buffer to
[4 * 229 * 229 * 3] so it can match with the inputfeature0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I don't know why does this occurs but it is maybe because of `DataType.FLOAT32`. I printed both buffers and found the total size was different.

```
Log.d("shape", byteBuffer.toString())
Log.d("shape", inputFeature0.buffer.toString())
```

My `inputFeature0.buffer` was `4-times` bigger that `byteBuffer`. Found it by dividing the both buffers. The solution i got from someplace it was

> You should multiply your buffer with 4.

According to their explanation my buffer should be like this

```
buffer = image.width x image.height x colorChanels x 4
```

But i don't know how to change the total buffer instead is double the `width` and `height` to have the same effect.

Try using `458` x `458` image size.